# How to change css on multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make so that each 3 elements (top, middle and bottom) of my polygon changes color when you hover over it. I would normally do it with css: `xxx:hover` but since it involves 3 different elements that need to change at the same time, I can only assume that I need take a different approach. I assume some sort of javascript? Ideas?

CODEPEN: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/shfge

**HTML**

```
<div class="hex-row even">
  <div class="hex">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="hex">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="hex">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="hex-row">
  <div class="hex">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="hex">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="hex">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="hex">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.hex {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-bottom: -26px;
}
.hex:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.hex .top {
    width: 0;
    border-bottom: 30px solid #6C6;
    border-left: 52px solid transparent;
    border-right: 52px solid transparent;
}
.hex .middle {
    width: 104px;
    height: 60px;
    background: #6C6;
}
.hex .bottom {
    width: 0;
    border-top: 30px solid #6C6;
    border-left: 52px solid transparent;
    border-right: 52px solid transparent;
}
.hex-row {
    clear: left;
}
.hex-row.even {
    margin-left: 53px;
}
```

Comment: do you want all the hex to change colors or just an hex element?

Comment: @SamBattat, sorry should have clarified that. One single hex. So basically the hex top,middle and bottom classes of one hex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not too hard, just target the .hex container and it's children like so:

```
.hex:hover .top {
  border-bottom-color: red;
}

.hex:hover .middle {
 background: Red;
}

.hex:hover .bottom {
  border-top-color: red;  
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GboDw

Comment: You can also use the `nth-child` selector along with the code @mikerobinson posted to set different hover colours for the first, second and third `<div class="hex">` inside each `<div class="hex-row even">`.